# How Pocket put their saved message above Safari

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, safari

My question is about how Pocket actually put their "saved" view above the Safari view. You can see it happen in [this video](http://pocket-blog.s3.amazonaws.com/20140915/Pocket%20share%20option%20final.gif).

Did they actually have access to put their view in Safari's view? Or is Safari in charge of this view?

I am talking about this [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done via an [App Extension](https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/).

Safari passes information to Pocket, via the share action sheet.  Pocket acts on it, and presents its momentary view above Safari, not within the browser.  Safari has nothing to do with what Pocket displays.